# Dynamic Table row not binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is the code which i use to append table row,where personTabs is the iframe name

```
$(".addClass1").on('click',function() {
           parent.parent.parent.personTabs.$("#skilltableId").append(                        
                  '<tr id="skilltableId1"><td class="btnRemoving">'+$("#selecetedValue").val()+'</td><td class="editing">'+$("#type").val()+'</td><td style="display:none">'+$("#commonDbid").val()+'</td></tr><br>'                    
        );
```

when i click td class='editing', i am generating a textbox as follows..

```
 parent.parent.parent.personTabs.$(".editing").on('click',function() {
                    var data = $(this).text();
                     $(this).html("<input type='text' id='focus123' value='"+data+"'/>").children().focus();
                      });
```

I am getting everything fine for the first time..the table row is been appended fine..when i do the same append for the second time,table row is generated.onclick working only for the last generated row..but not previous one..why is it so..anybdy here can tel me,..i tried live,delegate methods..but none worked..i am using jquery-1.9.1.js

Comment: Java **is not** JavaScript

Comment: Can you attach the markup? mabe create jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one problem is that you have created a text box with the same id. 
I am not sure why you used parent.parent.parent...

```
 $(".addClass1").on('click',function() {
           $("#skilltableId").append(                        
                  '<tr id="skilltableId1"><td class="btnRemoving">'+$("#selecetedValue").val()+'</td><td class="editing">'+$("#type").val()+'</td><td style="display:none">'+$("#commonDbid").val()+'</td></tr><br>'                    
        ); 

$(".editing").on('click',function() {
                var data = $(this).text();
                 $(this).html("<input type='text' class='focus123' value='"+data+"'/>").children().focus();
                  });
```

I am not sure if it will work or not, but you can also use this javascript function

```
$(".addClass1").on('click', function () {
    $("#skilltableId").append('<tr id="skilltableId1"><td class="btnRemoving">' + $("#selecetedValue").val() + '</td><td class="editing" on click="myfunction(this)">' + $("#type").val() + '</td><td style="display:none">' + $("#commonDbid").val() + '</td></tr><br>');

    function myfunction(selectedTd) {
        var data = $(selectedTd).text();
        $(selectedTd).html("<input type='text' class='focus123' value='" + data + "'/>").children().focus();

    }
});
```

Comment: @Mohammed.ur code works..in myfunction i am writing the following code to hide the textbox when i click td for second time..$("#skilltableId1 .editing").on('blur','#focus123',function() {
 $(this).parent().html($(this).val());
 }); and also td disappears.but i need the textbox to be created for that second selected td..how to do that?

Comment: why don't you send the full code, HTML+ javascript, I will send you the complete solution or you can jsfiddle it.

Comment: the pblm is that i cannot generate dynamic id to the dynamically created textbox.how to access from parent to child page?.. i am using jquery blur in child page

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x2F6M/1/ i made some more changes. Hope this will be perfect.

Comment: when we add dynamic row for the first time,its showing text acc to my logic.during second time,its showing textbox,but previous one is not hided..

Comment: I am not sure why it is giving problem. As I said if you can show me your html+javascript, the code that you shared on jsfiddle is not working.